# google maps - marker select list highlight list and vice versa

Tags: javascript, maps, markers

Does anyone have a reference or code snippet to accomplish this.  The ability to have a map with points and if you hover over the points the list of items highlight or vice versa if you hover over the list of items the map markets highlight.

ex. https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=tacos&find_loc=san+francisco

Answer (score 0):

It is working, when you hover on the list on Firefox 50.1.0, but it might be impossible to make it work the other way around, when you select a point on the map, to highlight a place on the list. I may be wrong, but it seems impossible, because it all depends on the code provided by Google maps. You would need to make a work around (hack) to get it work.